# Hacer esto es una buena practica?

Tags: php, wordpress, php7

estoy trabajando con WordPress, pero me surgió la duda de si es buena practica hacer tantos `echo` para no estar abriendo y cerrando la etiqueta de `php` cada que escribiré una de `html`

Les comparto un ejemplo de como he escrito parte de una función para mostrar unas entradas.

```
function lista_clases(){
    echo '<ul class="lista-clases">';

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'clase',
            'post_per_page' => 10,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );

        $clases = new WP_Query($args);

        while($clases -> have_posts()){

            $clases -> the_post();

            echo '<li class="clase card">
                <h1>';
                    the_post_thumbnail('pequeño');
                    echo '<div class="contenido">

                        <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">
                            <h3>';
                                the_title();
                        echo '</h3>
                        </a>';
                        $hora_inicio = get_field('hora_inicio');
                        $hora_fin = get_field('hora_fin');

                        echo '<p>';
                            the_field('dias_clase');
                        echo '- </p>';
                            echo $hora_inicio .' - '. $hora_fin;
                    echo '</div>
                </h1>
            </li>';

        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: En este punto considero que dado que tienes una función, lo mejor es: declarar al inicio una varibale, esta va ir llenándose como: **`$variable.=`** en cada sección donde vas construyendo la salida del HTML, entonces hasta que terminaste de llenar dicha variable haces al final un `return` de la misma

Comment: por lo general se manipula el output cache, dejando los tags html y haciendo echo de los datos

Comment: Oh ya veo, en realidad no se por que no lo pense de esa manera. Muchas gracias!

Comment: como tal, es mala practica, por el hecho de que mezclas php y html. Lo suyo seria utilizar un sistema de plantillas (tipo twig, blade,...) y que la logica este en la parte de php, y cuando quieras dibujar el html utilice la plantilla correspondiente. No estoy seguro si wordpress utiliza algun sistema de estos (creo que no).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma bastante estándar de hacerlo es manipulando el output buffer, algo así:

```
<?php
function lista_clases(){
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'clase',
    'post_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
  );
  $clases = new WP_Query($args);
  $output = "";
  // iniciar captura del output buffer
  ob_start();?>
  <ul class="lista-clases">
    <?php while( $clases->have_posts() ){
      $clases->the_post();
      // definir variables al principio del bloque
      $hora_inicio = get_field('hora_inicio');
      $hora_fin = get_field('hora_fin');
      ?>
      <li class="clase card">
        <h1><?php the_post_thumbnail('pequeño');?>
          <div class="contenido">
            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>"><h3><?php
            the_title();?></h3></a>
            <p><?php the_field('dias_clase'); ?> - </p>
            <?php echo "{$hora_inicio} - {$hora_fin}";?>
          </div>
        </h1>
      </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <?php
  wp_reset_postdata();
  // terminar la captura y asignar a una variable
  $output = ob_get_clean();

  echo $output;

  // una buena idea es que la función retorne el html
  // y luego este se imprima donde se usa
  // return html_entity_decode($output);
}
```

- fijate con el coloreo de sintaxis cómo queda mas claro todo ( y se puede apreciar que hay un `h1` englobando un `h3` )

[image: coloreo de sintaxis y estructura]

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dice @BetaM en su comentario, si quieres evitar la constante apertura/cierre de bloques PHP/HTML puedes crear una variable e ir recogiendo en ella la información mediante concatenación. Aquí, he creado una variable `$mHTML` con la cual ser irá recogido la información durante todo el código.

He simplificado algunas cosas y (corregido) otras. Allí donde lo he hecho he puesto comentarios, si no te conviene así, puedes ponerlo como lo tenías originalmente, pero debes saber que el objetivo es crear también un HTML válido. Aunque generalmente HTML no da error, cuando creas HTML inválido ocurren daños colaterales, como ser penalizado a nivel de SEO.

```
function lista_clases(){
    $mHTML="";
    $mHTML.='<ul class="lista-clases">';

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'clase',
            'post_per_page' => 10,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );

        $clases = new WP_Query($args);

        while($clases -> have_posts()){

            $clases -> the_post();

            $mHTML.='<li class="clase card">';
                /*
                    Las etiquetas h... son para encabezados
                    no para encerrar bloques completos
                    quizá conviene cerrar el h1 aquí
                */
                $mHTML.='<h1>'.the_post_thumbnail('pequeño').'</h1>';
                    $mHTML.= '<div class="contenido">
                        <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">
                            <h3>'.the_title().'</h3>
                        </a>';
                        $hora_inicio = get_field('hora_inicio');
                        $hora_fin = get_field('hora_fin');

                        $mHTML.= '<p>'.the_field('dias_clase').'- </p>';
                        /*
                            Esto es lo que guardabas en $hora_inicio 
                            y en $hora_fin, lo concatenamos directamente
                            es raro que eso no vaya dentro de alguna etiqueta ¿?
                        */
                        $mHTML.= get_field('hora_inicio').' - '. get_field('hora_fin');
                    $mHTML.=  '</div>';
                /*
                    Es muy raro meter TODO UN BLOQUE, con div incluido
                    dentro de una etique h1
                    estas etiquetas se usan para encabezados, no par bloques
                    de ahí la "h", que significa "header", encabezado
                    Lo he comentado aquí, porque más arriba cerramos el h1
                    Si lo haces así tu HTML sería inválido, aunque funcione
                */    
            $mHTML.='</li>';

        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

    $mHTML.= '</ul>';
    /*
        En algunos contextos, convendría un return
        en lugar de un echo
    */
    echo $mHTML;
}
```

Comment: Lo hice como ambos me indicaron y efectivamente funcionaba pero no completamente. Al momento de actualizar la pagina con el codigo que me proporcionaron todo el estilo fallaba y usando el inspector de elementos del navegador, me percataba que efectivamente el codigo HTML se imprimia correctamente, pero lo que se imprimia con PHP se impria fuera de todas las etiquetas de HTML, si cambiaba a mi codigo original funcionaba con normalidad... ignoro el por que sucede eso y por mas que modificaba su codigo, seguia ocurriendo lo mismo